# Listview order?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i have parsed with JSOUP a html table... it's ok!
but when android shows my listview it's ordered inverse...
i want for 1st PISA flight and second Roma ciampino..

Code edited... sorry

i want invert the rows for the listview 
This listview can container more flights!

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should see the "recicle view" in ListView to get performance.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't focus on inverting the order of the data in the `Adapter`. Try to invert the list of data before you

So you have your array `lista`before you create your adapter with `lista` do the following:

```
String[] invertedList = new String[lista.length];

for(int i = 0; i < lista.length; i ++) {
    invertedList[i] = lista[lista.length - 1 - i];
}
```

And then create your adapter with `invertedList` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i can't why into my lista[] there are:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7248880/

this is my list[] but i can't inverted order with:

```
    String[] invertedList = new String[lista.length];

for(int i = 0; i < lista.length; i ++) {
    invertedList[i] = lista[lista.length - 1 - i];
}
```

else invertedList[1] is ugual at "In orario" and into Compagnia print "In Orario"
it's possible inverted only rows? 
Do you understand me?

SOLVED: i have printed lista in reverse mode and changed order textview :(
Thank you so much